# How to receive only one packet from tcp socket quickly java

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, inputstream

The remote Tcp Server device sends out 8 bytes of data at a time and does so at relatively fast pace(but not horribly fast). Anyways, i want to receive the 8 bytes and enact on the 8 bytes given. However, i appear to be receiving bytearrays with multiples of these 8 bytes back to back to where my count(in code) is several multiples of 8 bytes, varying in length from 16 to 120+ bytes.

Checking Wireshark, the remote Tcp Server appears to be sending out the 8 bytes correctly and not combining them. This shows me that the reading of the socket is too slow and thus combining the 8 bytes intervals back to back for me, which i don't want.? An example being:

8bytes-8bytes-16bytes-8bytes-8bytes-56bytes.

here is a timestamping of how soon data streams in. with as little as 10 ms.

```
(13:44:23.210) 00h 10h 01h 06h FFh 3Ah FFh FFh
(13:44:23.290) 00h 10h 01h 06h FFh 3Fh FFh FFh
(13:44:23.300) 00h 10h 01h 06h FFh 44h FFh FFh
```

How do i efficiently read from the port to be as fast as possible while ensuring no multiples of the 8 byte data?

The code below is a segment that reads data of unknown size and posts it back to the NetworkManager for further processing. I have tried using different streams in hopes of getting the desired effect, but neither stream ensures that.

```
    private class Receive extends Thread {

        private InputStream inputStream;
        private DataInputStream dataInputStream;
        private BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
        private ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;

        public void run() {
            if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG + " \"" + name + "\"", String.valueOf(getId()) + ":receive run.");
            bundle = new Bundle();
            buffer = new byte[1024];
            try {
                bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                Log.d(TAG + " \"" + name + "\"", String.valueOf(getId()) + ":IOException", ioException);
            }
            while (connected && !closed) {
                if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG + " \"" + name + "\"", String.valueOf(getId()) + ":retry read.");
                try {
//                    socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
                    int count = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer);
                    byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(count);
                    if (count == -1) {
                        networkManager.stopTcpNetwork(name);
                        closed = true;
                        Log.d(TAG + " \"" + name + "\"", String.valueOf(getId()) + "Connection Lost?!?!");
                    } else {
                        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG + " \"" + name + "\"", String.valueOf(getId()) + ":call back." + " Count: " + String.valueOf(count));
                        byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        bundle.putByteArray(name, byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
//                        bundle.putByteArray(name, buffer);
                        message = networkManager.obtainMessage();
                        message.what = Messages.MESSAGES_TCP_DATA.getInt();
                        message.setData(bundle);
                        networkManager.sendMessage(message);
                    }
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException socketTimeoutException) {
                    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG + " \"" + name + "\"", String.valueOf(getId()) + ":no data yet.");
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    Log.d(TAG + " \"" + name + "\"", String.valueOf(getId()) + ":Exception", exception);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `buffer = new byte[8];` ?

Comment: @greenapps does this effectively speed up the read operation?

Comment: Why do you think so? And why do you ask?

Comment: What you see happening is quite normal using TCP. It's called buffering. What is so difficult to do one read of 1000 bytes in a buffer and then handle in a loop 8 bytes every time until the buffer is empty or less than 8 bytes left which can happen too but which you did not notice?

Comment: @greenapps When the buffer is left at any number higher than 8 bytes, the bufferedInputStream seems to sporadically return a count that is larger than just the expected 8 bytes. I appears that the phone is taking too long in the read operation that causes it to buffer up additional 8 bytes. i would think the phone would be fast enough to capture the frequent packets but appears to be too slow. i need to speed up the read operation or find a better way.

Comment: i would like to not to modify the buffer size because larger data may need to be processed too.

Comment: Sorry i expect reads of 1024 bytes every time. Not about 32 which you seem to suggest.

Comment: `relatively fast pace(but not horribly fast)` ?? Please be exact. This tells us nothing.

Comment: `byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()`. Who is resetting the contents of that stream? Doesnt the array grow?

Comment: oops.. updated the code section to be more inline with the actual code. it doesn't get reset, it merely creates a new one. because flushing it doesn't appear to erase the internal buffer of the byteArrayOutputStreem.

Comment: If you only want eight byes at a time, only read eight bytes at a time. Hard to see what the mystery is here. You should use `DataInputStream.readFully()` for this. You don't need a `ByyeArrayOutputStream` in this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The socket just buffers the data before it gets read into a buffer i guess. As others have pointed out, the correct answer is to either read everything in from the socket or only read an expected number of bytes from the socket.

anyways the project grew and the data that was needed to pull in also grew. that being said, the easiest way to done was to send the data back to the other thread to be locally buffered and then ultimately cycled through for potential messages(that are checked to be complete) and processed onward.

So, Hopefully this helps others.. if not, oops and sorry.
Thanks to all who commented and helped!

Comment: The 'most direct answer' was posted in a comment at 20:07 on 24 August 2016, and there is nothing here that actually answers the question.